# AS3: How to refer an object by his properties

Tags: actionscript-3, object, properties, refer

Well, I'm doing a checkers game and I need to refer a piece by its position (x and y, both) and remove it from the screen (no problem with this).

I've been traying combinations with "this." but nothing.
How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

this.x and this.y are functional from the scope of your checkers pieces object; however, if you're accessing a piece outside of their scope, you must use a piece's instance name.  Although not optimal, you could loop through children DisplayObjects.

```
// create a collection of your checker pieces
var checkers:Array = [];

// create a checker piece, whatever your DisplayObject class is.
var checker:Checker;
checkers.push(checker);

// add it to the stage, probably your game board
addChild(checker);    
checker.x = 100;
checker.y = 100;

// loop through the children (from your game board)
for (var i:uint = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    var checker:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
    trace(checker.x);
    trace(checker.y);
}
```

Using coordinates to reference a piece may not be optimal for game play.  You might want to consider a row / column or approach it from how your game board works.

If this is not clear, you should specify some code or expand your question with more detail.

Comment: All the checkers are from the class Checker (extended from MovieClip) and checker.side is a property of kind strig that can be "white" or "black". When they are positioned on the screen an array is created to store their relative position. So, the checkers have also _row (from 0 to 7) and _column (from 0 to 7 too), and the array is updated after every movement in order to calculate if a movement is possible or not. But the checkers are not in an array, should I do what you have done in your example code an find them by _row and _column?

Comment: I followed your example and it worked, all I needed was adding all the checkers in an array and the magic line "var checker:DisplayObject = getChildAt(0);" to verify one by one wich checker has that property and remove it.  
I modified your las part of the example to try it:
`function removeChecker (event:TimerEvent){  
     for(var i:uint = 0; i<checkers.length; i++){<br/>
 var checker:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);<br/>
 if (checker.x==200 && checker.y==200){<br/>
     removeChild(checker);<br/>
 }<br/>
     }<br/>
}`<br/>

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, sorry I had getChildAt(0) - you're exactly correct.  Thanks!